# Convert .help to .pdf

Tags: macos, pdf, file-conversion

I can save in .pdf just one or two pages at one time, using default Mac viewer. But I have several hundred of pages to save. Does anyone know how to do it faster?

Comment: Could you provide more information?  What program are you using to generate the PDF files?  What program are you using to "save in .pdf"?  By "default Mac viewer", do you mean the Preview application?

Comment: Looks similar to http://superuser.com/questions/46257/convert-microsoft-hlp-to-something-else-printable

Answer (score 1):

You could try importing the individual pages inside the help files into Calibre and then export as a book format or PDF

Since the .help files are just HTML pages, this could work but I guess the linking might not work correctly

Here's a page from the [Calibre features talking about HTML pages import](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/faq.html#how-do-i-convert-a-collection-of-html-files-in-a-specific-order)